# QGIS Table Manager plugin does not appear

Tags: qgis, table

I installed Table Manager Plugin, but cannot find it under the plugin menu. Anybody know where to find it?
[image: plugin is installed]
[image: but it not appear under plugin menu]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In QGIS 2.8, you can find it either in the `Vector` menu, or in the left panel:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 2.12.3 (Lyon), you will find the Table Manager plugin here.
[image: Table Manager]

Note that you will need to click on this icon before the menu appears.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Little tip: ***usually*** the *category* mentions which toolbar the plugin will be in. So for Table Manager, it is said to be in the **Vector** category/toolbar (which can be seen clearly in the previous answers):

[image: Category for plugin]

Note that this is not always the case (but would be useful if it was methinks).